# Compiles but gives "Error #1034: Type Coercion failed" during test

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flashdevelop

I am working on a flash based web application. The front end is written in flex: MXML and ActionScript. The project builds fine in FlashDevelop, but when I test that using F5, it throws error.

Line of code:

```
[Bindable]
public var currentStateDataProvider:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
```

Error message:

```
[Starting debug session with FDB]
[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert mx.collections::ArrayCollection@c2acfc9 to Array.
```

Is there anything wrong the way I am declaring and initializing the variable?

Comment: This isn't uncommon.  The likely solution,  is not instantiate the object in the var declaration.   Move the `new ArrayCollection();` into the constructor instead. In AS3 it's always better to not instantiate complex objects in the class var declarations

Comment: Worked! Is there any specific reason why this happens? The application I am working on was written 3-4 years ago; it worked fine then, but now I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error comes from the use of the varible. The declaration and instantiation seem good and they not should be the problem.
Anyway, i'm agree with the comment of [BadFeelingAboutThis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457439/badfeelingaboutthis). To do the instantiation of complex variables in the constructor is better for me.